# Does Pokemon use any deep A.I in battle?

Tags: game-design

A Pokemon wild battle. The enemy may have up to 4 moves.

I am wondering, is there any.. A.I going on here, or does the enemy simply take a random move and then executes it? Are there not any battle factors/conditions that may change the enemy's behavior?

I guess it makes sense to categorize moves by "Offensive" "Defensive" and/or "Healing", and from there make choices depending on HP etc... dunno.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve with this question? Are you trying to make your own battle system?

Comment: Well, yeah. I do not necessarily need to know the above to make my system, but I do feel curious about Pokemon's mechanics.

Comment: I have vague memories of Rattata Tail-Whipping 5 times in a row. No way a sane AI would do something like that.

Comment: If I remember correctly, tail-whip reduces defense. Reducing defense when the player has a pokemon with a much higher attack power is a natural thing to do, especially when it's followed up by a tackle. So there might be some very basic AI going on here

Comment: If this question is about how the AI works in Pokemon, it might be better to ask gaming.SE though you should include which version of Pokemon you're asking about.  If you're asking about how to make a Pokemon style battle system AI, then you should rephrase the question.

Answer (score 2):

Wild Pokémon use very simple AI to reflect having not much of a clue on their own. Trainers' mons use a more complicated system, where one of the bytes in the trainer data determines how smart *that trainer* is.

Comment: Can you please edit to include the source of this information?

Comment: Observation of how often a bad move is picked, and having seen and edited the trainer data myself. But I'll see if there's better... This is observed from the GBA games, by the way.

Comment: Nope, can't seem to find anything on my regular source (Bulbapedia). They didn't have any back then and they still don't.

Comment: http://helmet.kafuka.org/fulltrainers.html